# Unable to figure out accurate query to get timestamps for my report

Tags: sql, reporting-services, timestamp, reportbuilder3.0

I am trying to write a report based on data of users logging into a session.

I need to be able to get a full session time from when the first person joins the meeting to when the last person leaves.

- When someone joins a meeting it is logged as, "Initialize-Load Video chat Window"
- There are 2 ways to close the meeting but one way is being logged.
  - There is an "End Chat" button that the user can use and that is logged as, "Video Chat-End Chat"
  - If the user does not use that button and just exits out the program/browser, the database does not log that, and I would like to use the last logged element in the logType column.

I would like it to look like this below:
[image]

This is my query:

```
select vl.originalChatSessionID, 
       CONVERT(DATE, min(vl.ReceivedDateTime)) as VideoDate, 
       --CONVERT(TIME, min(vl.ReceivedDateTime)) as StartTime,
       min(vl.ReceivedDateTime) as StartTime2,
       --CONVERT(TIME, max(vl.ReceivedDateTime)) as EndTime,
       max(vl.ReceivedDateTime) as EndTime2,
       DATEDIFF(MINUTE, min(vl.ReceivedDateTime), max(vl.ReceivedDateTime)) as SessionLength
from iclickphrDxvideolog vl
    --inner join iclickphrDxVideoHistory vh
    --  on vl.originalChatSessionID = vh.meetingid
    --  and vl.applicationUserID = vh.applicationUserID
where originalChatSessionID = @MeetingSessionID
    --and (vl.logType = 'Initialize-Load Video chat Window' or vl.logType = 'Video Chat-End Chat')
group by originalChatSessionID
```

Problem is I am grabbing the first logged element and last logged element in the logType column, and I know that.  If i uncomment the part in the where clause where it says; --and (vl.logType = 'Initialize-Load Video chat Window' or vl.logType = 'Video Chat-End Chat'), then i do not have an issue with the Start time of the session....but have a big issue with the End Time of the session.

Below is a picture of how the raw data looks:

[image]

Comment: You should probably look into some `partition over` queries and/or sub-queries.

Comment: You say you have a problem with your current approach where the second "where condition" is commented but you dont say why that approach is not acceptable / what problem there is with it. As I understand your question you are trying to get the earliest and the latest activity for a particular call and that approach would seem to satisfy that.

Comment: @GB I mentioned that when i uncomment it out from the where condition, the end time gets messed up.  Because if i do not have the "Video Chat-End Chat" log in the db, it does not grab the very last item in the logType column, because im only filtering that column by 'Initialize-Load Video chat Window' and "Video Chat-End Chat"....but that ruins the EndTime.  Does that makes sense?

Comment: @Marc I tried to doing a sub query but failed at that.  I'm new to sql so trying to figure it out.  I have never used partition over.  Can you please explain how to use that more?

Comment: Are you trying to get the earliest and the latest activity for a particular call?
If yes, your current query (forget about the commented bits) appears to do that. What am I missing?

Comment: @GB I am trying to get the earliest and latest activity.  The problem is the call/log for End chat is not always logged.  So i want to grab the latest activity in that column....that isnt the Load video chat and the end chat...i want the latest of any activity that is in the logType column.  If you look at my raw data pic...you can see theres several different items in that column.

Comment: I can see there are log entries prior to "load chat" that you want to filter out but I cannot see if there are entries after "end chat" that you want to filter out. Ultimately (as you have found) you cannot filter on entries if they are not in the log, does it make more sense to filter out the entries which you want to exclude i.e. prior to load and after end chat.

Comment: @GB the problem is what can be logged before and after the start and end chat is very random.  So wont be able to filter that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've a assumed that `originalChatSessionID` defines a unique session. If not then you will have to change the 'PARTITION BY' clause to mirror the column or columns that make it unique.

This also assumes that `ReceivedDateTime` is a `datetime` datatype

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       vl.originalChatSessionID, 
       VideoDate = MIN(vl.ReceivedDateTime) OVER(PARTITION BY originalChatSessionID), 
       StartTime = MIN(ISNULL(sc.StartChat, vl.ReceivedDateTime)) OVER(PARTITION BY originalChatSessionID),
       EndTime = MAX(ISNULL(ec.EndChat, vl.ReceivedDateTime)) OVER(PARTITION BY originalChatSessionID),
       SessionLength = DATEDIFF(
                minute,
                MIN(ISNULL(sc.StartChat, vl.ReceivedDateTime)) OVER(PARTITION BY originalChatSessionID), 
                MAX(ISNULL(ec.EndChat, vl.ReceivedDateTime)) OVER(PARTITION BY originalChatSessionID)
                )
    FROM iclickphrDxvideolog vl
        LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT originalChatSessionID, StartChat = MIN(ReceivedDateTime) 
                        WHERE logType = 'Initialize-Load Video chat Window'
                        GROUP BY originalChatSessionID
                    ) sc ON vl.originalChatSessionID = sc.originalChatSessionID
        LEFT JOIN (
                    SELECT originalChatSessionID, EndChat = MAX(ReceivedDateTime) 
                        WHERE logType = 'Video Chat-End Chat'
                        GROUP BY originalChatSessionID
                    ) ec ON vl.originalChatSessionID = ec.originalChatSessionID
```

This is untested as I don't have time to recreate your dataset. If you need more help I suggest you post a script to recreate your sample data so people can use it to test against.

The above uses two sub queries, one to get the first instance of `Initialize-Load Video chat Window` and one to get the last instance of `Video Chat-End Chat`. I have `LEFT JOIN`ed to these so they will return `NULL` values is nothing is found. In the main part of the query, I've used `ISNULL()` to test if the start record is not found then use the earliest record for the session and if the end record is not found then use the last record for the session.

> Note that there is no grouping but I have used `DISTINCT` to get a
> similar result. This SQL statement does not have a WHERE clause so you
> could create a view from it then simply use that view with a WHERE
> clause for your report.

Comment: can you take a look at this? Thanks

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64840961/unable-to-figure-out-accurate-query-to-get-timestamps-for-my-report-for-each